# android: retain image in display once loaded from url?

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-gridview

i am retriving around 20 images url from an xml , and appearing them in gridview.
thing going nice except one.

when i scroll down **new images start loading** ,  but when i again scrolls up. the previously loaded images **again stars loading** .

how can i resolve this bug. the previously loaded image should be retained in the layout , why it is not retaining itself .

I am using the adapter extends the BaseAdapter  to view the images

Comment: when i scroll down and up , the image adapter's getview method is executing which is again loading the images...

Comment: post some code, but the most immediate explanation is that you download the image in the getView, which is called every time the image needs to be viewed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gridview like any other views that inherit AdapterView only uses the amount of views that you see on the screen. So when you scroll your views going to be reused. The Adapter's responsibility is to reassign the content to the views.

So, you need to cache your bitmaps. There is a very nice tutorial about this on the Android developer side. 
http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html

(I uses grid view in the example)

Comment: you took me to a very good tutorial , but the tutorial is very complex , i have to first go through the whole program and then will inmplement in mine , thanx dude

Answer (score 1):

Every time you scroll, getView() method of the adapter is called.

So every time one view come in to the screen is built in the getView() method.
You build the new view in that method, I suppose you download the image when that method is called, then one solution is caching the images. If you download few images and they are small size, a simply Map with key url and value bitmap solves the problem, if not, use database.

Every time getView() is called, check first if image is in cache, if image is in cache use it to build the view, if not download it.

Comment: you shouldn't store images in the database.

Comment: If your heap consumption grows to limits because of store bitmaps in memory, sure you should, unless you don't mind to download images one time and over and over.

Comment: what i meant was that you shouldn't insert the image into a database, you should store it on disk, and if you want, store the path of the image in a database. otherwise in this case it doesn't seem practical to store it in the database.

Comment: Oh that's for sure, store path in database to find image on disk. (Well, all is disk: database, file system...;D)

Answer (score 1):

use LoaderImageView from this blog http://blog.blundell-apps.com/imageview-with-loading-spinner/ & add following function

```
public void setImageDrawable(final MyGridViewItem obj) {
                mDrawable = null;
                if(obj.mDrawable != null){
                      mDrawable = obj.mDrawable
                imageLoadedHandler.sendEmptyMessage(COMPLETE);
                 return;
                }
                mSpinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                new Thread(){
                        public void run() {
                                try {
                                          mDrawable = getDrawableFromUrl(imageUrl);
                                           obj.mDrawable = mDrawable;

                                        imageLoadedHandler.sendEmptyMessage(COMPLETE);
                                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                                        imageLoadedHandler.sendEmptyMessage(FAILED);
                                } catch (IOException e) {
                                        imageLoadedHandler.sendEmptyMessage(FAILED);
                                }
                        };
                }.start();
        }
```

Comment: i have used this code in getview method, but get view method keeps calling this and my pereviously loaded image again starts loading

Comment: that will happen till the image downloads 1st time then it not download the image again

Comment: yah there is a change in your program , buddy , what are you passing in "final MyGridViewItem obj" as parameter.

Comment: user the Custom class to keep the list item & in item keep your data like list item desc, image etc.